# How to have separate instance of ViewModel in each Fragment and have shared data as well between Viewmodels

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am working on Android TV app
And I have a Fragment(main Fragment) and inside fragment have side menu, each menu Item creates new fragment(menu Fragment).
I have Viewmodel and in ViewModel I have config livedata which I am loading when I main Fragment is created.
And Menu Fragment's data is based on data I am getting from API calls and from config data

I have created single instance of viewmodel with the activity lifecycle.
But the problem is when I am navigating from one fragment to another for example from 1-2 fragment and as 1 fragment has already loaded data the livedata is not empty and navigating to 2nd fragment before fetching the second fragment data it observes/displays the livedata from first fragment and then it's own after it fetches it's data
I think each fragment should have it's own instance ,but I also need data which should be shared (the config)  between the each instance of viewmodel ?
How can I make this?

```
  private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by lazyViewModelActivityScope()
viewModel.fetch()
   viewModel.configData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->
  loadData(it)
})
```

it is inside MenuFragment

```
  private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by lazyViewModelActivityScope()

 viewModel.fetchMenuPage(menuItem)
      viewModel.carouselsWithAssetsData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { carouselWithAssets ->
    carouselWithAssets.forEach { carouselWithAsset ->
      mRowsAdapter.add(createCardRow(carouselWithAsset))
    }
  })
```

Comment: Don't observe on Activity lifecycle. Try to observe on Fragment lifecycle. So that every time a Fragments gets created you get fresh new data.

Comment: Yes, but in that case how can I share data between viewModels  ?

Comment: I would suggest you to take two `ViewModels`, one is for every instance of fragments *(I.e. HomeViewModel)*, another is shared `ViewModel` *(I.e. SharedViewModel)*.

Comment: Yes and in that case which is the best way in ViewModel to have access to data of SharedViewMdoel data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer of my question and I want to share it with others

I think generally this is something you'd manage with DI (injecting the same config into both ViewModels)

Or each Fragment would need to pass the activity ViewModel's data to the Fragment's ViewModel. Or you could have a global LiveData that manages itself (loading data in `onActive()`) and skip the activity ViewModel entirely